# Markdown preview rendering difference when linking the file protocol

Tags: bug, markdown-preview

**Code:**

```markdown
From the [weakref documentation](file:///usr/share/doc/python3/html/library/weakref.html):
```

**Expected result:** link may or may not be active, but the markdown should parse. This works in the rendered output:

> [image]

**Actual result:** in the preview, the markdown does not parse and shows a different view compared to after hitting save.

> [image]

**Demo**: hit edit on this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/76577345/1201863

Comment: stray side-question- why would you do that though? I guess you could save some people a net request- _for those that have that file in that place_ and not everyone will.

Comment: @starball I had hoped it would show up as link, and while not everyone will have it there, it's the default install path on what I think is the most common distribution, so it could work for many developers. I find it nice to have offline, e.g. while traveling, but also simply to not ask a server to send me a file that I literally already have and which matches my exact Python version, so I have a shortcut to its `search.html`. Most people don't know they even have these files, so they would learn there's docs installed locally on their system and henceforth potentially get use out of them.

Comment: IMHO references in a post should work without having to use a particular OS, or having a particular package installed.

Comment: @DanMašek That's fair; it's auxiliary though, one can always type weakref into the python doc search and find the exact match as top hit. (Or, more likely, type it into a web-wide search engine and have it spend a little bit of carbon on finding this file they probably have locally.) If I had expected many people would want to click through, I'd indeed have linked an always-functional URL